# Write a function definition named quotient that takes in two numbers and returns the quotient of dividing the first argument by the second argument

Tags: javascript, function, return, operators

I am taking an assessment for JavaScript and I am stuck. I have tried tweaking and moving things around with no luck. Basically it is a series of questions that once answered correctly moves onto the next one. For this one there is this bit of info beneath the question.
this is what I have which is giving back expected: 2 & instead got: 2.5 in my console.

The question is to: Write a function definition named quotient that takes in two numbers and returns the quotient of dividing the first argument by the second argument.

`function quotient(x, x1) { return x = x / x1; }`

Comment: The `x =` is unnecessary (just `return x/x1` should be enough), but otherwise your code works.

Comment: There are these asserts below the question: assert(quotient(27, 9), 3, "Exercise 36");
assert(quotient(5, 2), 2, "Exercise 36");
assert(quotient(10, 3), 3, "Exercise 36");

Comment: "*giving back `expected: 2 & instead got: 2.5`*" - that sounds like maybe the function is supposed to do **integer division**, i.e. round the result down? Try adding `Math.floor(…)`. But that would mean the assessment is of really poor quality, this should have been mentioned explicitly. Maybe it was originally written for a different language and ported badly?

Comment: Try to seek clarification from the instructor/assessor in any case

Comment: ok let me do some research on Math.floor. I am a newbie and not familiar. thank you for helping

Comment: @Bergi an instructor responded with: Just doing straight division like 5 / 2 will return the quotient AND the remainder as a decimal number. In this case: 2.5
The problem ONLY wants the quotient (i.e., the whole number part) and NOT the remainder. In this case: 2 (or 2.0 should also be fine)
I suggest taking a look at the JavaScript math library and see which functions it provides that would return the whole number part of a decimal number:

Comment: Thanks, that seems to make it clear. [Defining the quotient as "the integer part of euclidean division" apparently is *less common*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient#Integer_part_definition), and I've never heard of it (in my native language), but still accepted. But the extended instruction settles it. Could you solve the exercise already? If so, you might want to [post an answer yourself](/help/self-answer).

Comment: no unfortunately I have not. I tried Math.ceil, Math.floor, and Math.round. I am not sure if it is the syntax. I read that they can be used for 1 value and my question has 2 values. so I thought if I entered both values in () after each Math. with a / it would work but nope. I am out of ideas at this point. Google only has for 1 value so maybe I am looking at this with the wrong frame of mind. I am definitely lost.

Comment: @Bergi I finally figured it out. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

> an instructor responded with:
>
> > Just doing straight division like 5 / 2 will return the quotient AND
> > the remainder as a decimal number. In this case: 2.5
> > The problem ONLY
> > wants the quotient (i.e., the whole number part) and NOT the
> > remainder. In this case: 2 (or 2.0 should also be fine)

With this clarification, it turns out they are looking for euclidian integer division. You can achieve this by using [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) on the result of the normal division:

```
function quotient(dividend, divisor) {
  var x = dividend / divisor;
  return Math.floor(x);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've finally got the answer. Thanks for helping!!

```
function quotient(x, y){
  return Math.floor(x / y);
}
```